# how to get the "real" value of i18next key with React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, i18next

I know how to run tests using i18n json keys but no idea how I can get the value of that key ? (the one that the user will see when translations will be loaded)

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Login from "../../pages/login/Login";
import { ThemeContextProvider } from "../../contexts/ThemeContext";

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key) => key }),
}));

const renderWithContext = () => {
  return render(
    <ThemeContextProvider>
      <Login />
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  );
};

describe("Test login", () => {
  it("test labels", () => {
    renderWithContext();
    screen.getByLabelText("Email");
    screen.getByLabelText("form.label.password");
  });
});
```